# how to write left join in codeigniter datatables? here is my code

Tags: php, codeigniter, datatables

```
$this->load->library('ssp');
                    $table = 'ip_users`,`ip_projects`,`ip_proj_additional_info';
                    $primaryKey = 'id';
                    $host = $this->db->hostname;
                    $username_host = $this->db->username;
                    $pass_host = $this->db->password;
                    $db = $this->db->database;
                    $sql_details = array(
                     'user' => $username_host,
                     'pass' => $pass_host,
                     'db'   => $db,
                     'host' => $host
                    );

                $columns = array(
                    array( 'db' => 'fname',                         'dt' => 0 ),
                    array( 'db' => 'lname',                         'dt' => 1 ),
                    array( 'db' => 'title',                         'dt' => 2 ),
                    array( 'db' => 'refund_status', 'dt' => 3 ),
                    array( 'db' => 'role',                          'dt' => 4 ),
                    array( 'db' => 'id',                            'dt' => 5 ),
                    array( 'db' => 'status',                        'dt' => 6 ),

                    );


                leftJoin( 'ip_proj_additional_info', 'ip_proj_additional_info.user_id', '=', 'ip_users.id' );
                leftJoin( 'ip_projects', 'ip_projects.project_id', '=', 'ip_proj_additional_info.pid' );

                if($type != ""){
                //waiting for refund
                if($type == "waiting_refund"){

                    $where = "ip_proj_additional_info.refund_status ='1'";


                }
                //refunded uses
                if($type == "refunded"){
                    $where = "ip_proj_additional_info.refund_status = '2'";
                }

            }else{

                $where = "";
            }
                $whereResult="";
                $output_array=SSP::complex( $_GET, $sql_details, $table,$primaryKey, $columns,$where,$whereResult);
                $result = $output_array['data'];
```

Answer (score 2):

It will help you.

```
    $this->db->select ( 'field_name' );
    $this->db->from ( 'table1 T1' );
    $this->db->join ( 'table2 T2', 'T1.id = T2.id', 'LEFT' );
    $this->db->where ( 'T1.id', $id );
    $query = $this->db->get ();
```

Comment: this code works only for writing query for normal tables in dynamic datatables  this query is not working   i have searched a lot and i got https://editor.datatables.net/manual/php/joins#leftJoin-method and i tried to implement the code prefered here and i got an undefined function left join error

Comment: if the dataTables method `leftJoin` is undefined then you have not loaded the dataTables Editor API. How are you integrating CodeIgniter with dataTables Editor?